# Saving content from html in a txt file

Tags: php, forms, vue.js, input, txt

I am trying to get a php request for an input field as well as a div, which gets its content via javascript. The request of the input-field works fine, how would I get the div-content into php, so I can get a txt-file extracted to the server.

Here is the html:

```
<form method="POST" id="someform">
  <input placeholder="Enter Email" type="email" name="email">
</div>
<div name="name">{{firstName}} {{lastName}}</div>
```

firstName and secondName are variables created with VueJs

Then I want to extract "email" and "name" to a txt-file with php like this:

```
<?php 
    extract($_REQUEST);
    $file=fopen("emails.txt", "a");

    fwrite($file,"email :");
    fwrite($file,  $email. "\n");
    fwrite($file,"name :");
    fwrite($file,  $name. "\n");
    fclose($file);
?>
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: You can't just add `name` to any html element and expect it to be sent with the form. You need to use a form element (input, textarea, select, button and such). You should also avoid using `extract()`  in this context since that doesn't only clutter the global namespace with a bunch of unknown variables, but can also cause some serious side effects if you're not careful. If it's a post request, just fetch the values from the `$_POST`-super global instead.

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass to your PHP file the VueJS variables like this:

```html
<form method="POST" id="someform">
  <input placeholder="Enter Email" type="email" name="email">
  <input type="hidden" value="{{firstName}}" name="firstName">
  <input type="hidden" value="{{lastName}}" name="lastName">
</div>
```